# Sketch3: How to enter in value for ruler guide instead of manually clicking position?

Tags: sketch-app, measurement, guides

When I want to add a ruler guide, how can I enter in an x/y value, instead of manually clicking where I want it? In Photoshop you can do so by clicking insert guide, then it gives you a value box, similarly with Illustrator you can type it in once the guide is selected. How about Sketch?

Comment: Check these plugins:  
https://github.com/petehouston/sketch-guides
   
https://github.com/joshpuckett/sketchplugins

Answer (score 1):

### You can't

Not elegantly anyway.

A hack I've used is to position a rectangle at the coordinates then align the guide to it. It's lame, but I don't use guides often.